# Multiple operators AND OR - Java

Tags: java, android, if-statement, operators

My code don't work. I expected to get the alert "You have xyz ....". Nothing happen. Its something wrong in the code?

```
 if ((event.values[0] == 1 || event.values[0] == 2 || event.values[0] == 3)&&
     (event.values[1] == 3 || event.values[1] == 4 || event.values[1] == 6)&&
     (event.values[2] == 7 || event.values[2] == 8 || event.values[2] == 9)) { 
      values.setText("You have xyz ...."); 
 }
```

Comment: That would depend upon the values inside of `event.values[]`

Comment: Have you tried printing the `values` before entering the condition to see if the meet the condition?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(event.values[1] == 4 || event.values[1] == 5 || event.values[1] == 6)` ?

Comment: Agreed. You have `1,2,3` - `3,4,6` - `7,8,9` Maybe that's what you want but it does seem odd.

Comment: Ok, thanks, now I know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntactic I don't see any obvious errors, however why you don't see your alert must be a result of incorrect values in your `event[]` variable. Have you tried debug your code?? To be sure what the values are?

Comment: Values have decimals. I observed this after Christian commented.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the variables are wrong.  I don't see a mistake in your code.

Comment: Just `19` more reputation and you will be able to comment. Go for it!

Comment: Thnx for the support :)